# (D3 line chart) Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm very new to D3.js. I'm trying to build a Line chart using **D3.js** and **angularjs**. I'm getting the above error.

The data in console which I'm passing through **rest services** looks like

```
    [{"id":1,"time":"Jun 19, 2017 13:17:21","ltp":9620.5,"time1":20170619},
    {"id":2,"time":"Jun 20, 2017 13:27:21","ltp":9617.7,"time1":20170620},
    {"id":3,"time":"Jun 21, 2017 13:36:51","ltp":9615.3,"time1":20170621}]
```

Below is my Controller class code in which i'm appending the chart.

```
var niftyController = function($scope,$http, $state, $stateParams, $location){
    var niftyController = this;
    $scope.loadNiftyData = function(){
        $http.get('/nifty')
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            var responseNifty = JSON.parse(response.data);

            $scope.chartConfig={
                data:[{}]
            };

            $scope.chartConfig.data.push(responseNifty);
            console.log(response.data);

            var chartConfig = $scope.chartConfig;
            var svgConfig = { id:"mySvg", width:600, height:300, margin : { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50 } };
            var bodySelection = d3.select("body"); var svgSelection = bodySelection.append("svg") .attr("id", svgConfig.id) .attr("width",svgConfig.width) .attr("height",svgConfig.height);

            xScale = d3.scale.linear() .range([ svgConfig.margin.left, svgConfig.width - svgConfig.margin.right ]) .domain([ d3.min(chartConfig.data, function(d) {return +d.time1;}), d3.max(chartConfig.data, function(d) {return +d.time1;}) ]);
            yScale = d3.scale.linear() .range([ svgConfig.height - svgConfig.margin.top, svgConfig.margin.bottom ]) .domain([ d3.min(chartConfig.data, function(d) {return +d.ltp;}), d3.max(chartConfig.data, function(d) {return +d.ltp;}) ]);

            xAxis = d3.svg.axis() .scale(xScale);
            yAxis = d3.svg.axis() .orient("left") .scale(yScale);

            svgSelection.append("svg:g") .attr("id","xAxis") .call(xAxis);
            d3.select("#xAxis") .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (svgConfig.height - svgConfig.margin.bottom) + ")");
            svgSelection.append("svg:g") .attr("id","yAxis") .call(yAxis);
            d3.select("#yAxis") .attr("transform", "translate(" + (svgConfig.margin.left) + ",0)");
            var lineSelection = d3.svg.line() .x(function(d){ return xScale(d.time1); }) .y(function(d){ return yScale(d.ltp) });
            svgSelection.append("svg:path") .attr('d', lineSelection(chartConfig.data)) .attr('stroke', 'green') .attr('stroke-width', 2) .attr('fill', 'none');

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    };
    $scope.loadNiftyData();
};
```

Please guide me to build the chart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to parse the dates and use a time scale. You cannot simply do `+d.time`, that's not a string containing numbers.

Comment: I'm using "time1" and "ltp" for x and y axis respectively. "time1" and "ltp" contains numbers.

Comment: Now I see it. Not the best name choice, though.

Comment: Sorry! for the name :) Please help me for building the chart. Thank you. @GerardoFurtado

Comment: Well, you have an angular problem somewhere else, because the D3 part of the code is OK, creating a normal path. This is a fiddle with that small data you copy/pasted: https://jsfiddle.net/74ok6k4f/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this.

In the above code, implementation of **$scope.chartConfig** is wrong. The correct method to be implemented is

```
$scope.chartConfig = {data:responseNifty};
```

in place of

```
$scope.chartConfig={
   data:[{}]
};
$scope.chartConfig.data.push(responseNifty);
```